# Scrapy and Selenium submit form that renders dynamically

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using selenium to first load the form which being generated via ajax.

Now I'm having troubles passing the selenium response to scrapy FormReuqest method

to send the form data values.

The form has jquery validation before user can submit it, does it make it harder to submit using scrapy?

any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please find all information here: http://pastebin.com/CLB8XMY0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need neither `Scrapy`, nor `selenium` here. Just make an underlying `POST` request and parse the json response. Example using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import json
import requests


URL = 'http://calculator.shipito.com/en/rates'
data = {"location": "10", "country": "GB", "city": "London",
        "postalcode": "123456", 
        "packages": [{"dimensions_units": "in", "weight_units": "lbs", "dimension": {"width": "9", "height": "20.4", "length": "17"},
        "weight": "9", "value": "170"}]}

response = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(data))
print response.json()
```

Prints:

```
[
    {u'infoUrl': u'http://www.shipito.com/postage#tnt', u'isPromoted': False, u'popularity': 1, u'name': u'TNT Economy', u'deliveryTime': 6, u'insurable': True, u'usesDimWeight': True, u'shippingRate': 68.38, u'separateShippingRate': None, u'bonusShippingRate': 68.38, u'deliveryTimeInfo': u'4-6 business days', u'mps': False, u'insuranceRate': 0, u'logoImg': u'tnt.png'}, 
    ...
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it using pure scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response() method?